# Duplicate Record Sets - Action on "Compare and Merge"

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, duplicate-management

How can i add an action (process builder or call Apex Class) on Duplicate Record Set Object when clicking this button on top right? Compare and merge? I want to add an action to somehow lock the record in order to notify the other users that may try to compare and merge the records, that already someone else is reviewing those records. I contacted Salesforce Support and told me i need to do it with Trigger, Apex. But triggers, at least as far as i know, are not able to show confirmation modal/screen...

[image]

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this with Duplicate Record Set trigger, as 'Compare and Merge' calls 'Potential Duplicate Records' which is standard and not customizable. A dirty workaround would be to write a trigger(update and delete) on your record(account/contact/lead) and use addError(errorMsg).

Comment: Yes i guess you're right:) Thanks!